# Javascript JSON request Blocked

Tags: javascript, json

I am running query requests from local host while developing a website. Every time I query from google or the address below I am no longer getting results. How can I avoid this? Are query limits set for certain URLS? What do you recommend and how can I avoid this upon production?

```
 function searchSymbol() {    
        ticker = "AAPL";


    var url="https://ir.stockpr.com/service/quote_jsonp?symbol=";
    var extra="&jsonp=quote_search";

    // Remove already existing script tag
    if(document.getElementById('myScript'))
        document.getElementById('myScript').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('myScript'));

    // Create script tag and add it to head
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url+ticker+extra;

    script.id = 'myScript';
    document.head.appendChild(script)
}

function quote_search(json) {       
    var tickerSymbol = json.symbol;
    var tickerPrice = json.last;
}
```

Comment: looks like the service is just down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change a url,you can not access even by browser,it returns

> Quotes are momentarily unavailable.

Comment: Im trying to find a URL that uses JSONP cant seem to find one that fits my setup

Comment: just a jsonp url ?don't care about data?

Comment: I just need last price and stock symbol

Comment: Google finance is blocking my queries

Comment: you have to wait for this url work or change another one ,the problem has noting to do with you,it is the problem of the website.

Comment: if you can access it in the browser,then you can access it in your script.I couldn't access it in the browser.you have to prove that the google finance is blocking your queries or i just believe the problem is that the url just doesn't work

Comment: but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.

Comment: that is what you got?i got :'Quotes are momentarily unavailable.'what is your status code?like 200 or 403 or others?i got 200